# scipy.io.loadmat() is causing a null pointer to PyImport_Import()

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio-2015, scipy

I am using scipy.io to load a .mat file through python. I then want to import this python script using c++ in visual studio.

Ex. 1:
testpython.py

```
    b=[0,1,2,3]
```

testimport.cpp

```
    PyObject *pName = PyUnicode_FromString((char*)"testpython");

    std::cout << pName << std::endl; 

    // Load the module object

    PyObject *pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);

    std::cout << pModule << std::endl;

    PyObject *b = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule, "b");

    std::cout << b << std::endl;

    PyObject *barray = PyArray_FromObject(b, NPY_DOUBLE, 1, 2);

    std::cout << barray << std::endl;
```

This works, but it is not what I want to do.

Ex. 2:

testpython.py

```
     import scipy.io as sio

     x=sio.loadmat('matfile.m')

     y=x['variable1']
```

testimport.cpp

```
     PyObject *pName = PyUnicode_FromString((char*)"testpython");

     std::cout << pName << std::endl; 

     // Load the module object

     PyObject *pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);

     std::cout << pModule << std::endl;

     PyObject *b = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule, "y");

     std::cout << b << std::endl;

     PyObject *barray = PyArray_FromObject(b, NPY_DOUBLE, 1, 2);

     std::cout << barray << std::endl;
```

pModule returns null and the code breaks when sio.loadmat is used in python, but it works when sio.loadmat is not used. Does anyone have any suggestions as to what is happening and how to address this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Does `testpython.py` run when used as Python script?  What is the resulting `y`? (shape, dtype).  Depending on the MATLAB source, the loadmat dictionary can be quite complicated.

Comment: The shape is (120,120,60) and the dtype is float64.

Comment: Yes, testpython.py runs in python.

Answer (score 0):

In the comments, you say `y` is 3D (shape 120x120x60). You've set an upper limit of 2D in your `PyArray_FromObject` call:

```
//                                                      v right here
PyObject *barray = PyArray_FromObject(b, NPY_DOUBLE, 1, 2);
```

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, the code breaks before it even reaches that line. pModule returns as null.